# Winforms listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two forms. In the 2 form I add mp3 file in a `textbox`. After closing the 2 form, I want to display the file information in a listbox in the 1 form.

2 Form:

```
    private void buttonChooseSong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.FileName = String.Empty;
        openfile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openfile.Filter = "MP3 File(*.mp3)|*.mp3";
        openfile.FilterIndex = 2;
        openfile.Multiselect = false;
        if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            song.Name = openfile.SafeFileName;
            song.Path = openfile.FileName;
            textBoxSongName.Text = openfile.SafeFileName;
            buttonAddSong.Visible = true;
            Song nsong = new Song();
        }
    }
    private void buttonAddSong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

What to do in 1 form to display the `mp3` file information in a `listbox`?

Comment: Define a public property in your Form2 to store the chosen song and access it from Form1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before. Just go to the Form1 and right click and go to designer, make your **Form1** objects `public`.

Like this:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxSongName;
```

> Just follow this

[image: Just follow this]